# How to define an action of scroll lock pressed in inittab?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I want a specific shell-script to be executed when I press the scroll lock key on my keyboard (I am using openSUSE 10.2). For this I want to edit the inittab (under /etc/initab/) like this:
*cb:12345:kbrequest:/home/user1/script.sh*
(the syntax for this is: *id:runlevels:action:process* - see man inittab or http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5)

But now I still don't know how or where to define my scrolllock key. The manual page says something of a keymap file. Where to find this?
And what to insert there? Is it:  keycode 70 = KeyboardSignal ?

Looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo 'keycode 70 = KeyboardSignal' | loadkeys
```

man loadkeys (in kbd package probably) will give you more info.